# Basemap Objects in 3D

Tags: python, 3d, matplotlib-basemap

Using Basemap in a 3D, calls such as
ax.add_collection3d(m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25))
work but calls with fill such as
ax.add_collection3d(m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='blue'))
do not work.

What is the correct way to add a filled map object to a 3D drawing?

Answer (score 0):

```
map = Basemap()
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.add_collection3d(map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25))
ax.add_collection3d(map.drawcountries(linewidth=0.35))
ax.add_collection3d(map.drawstates(linewidth = 0.1))
```

This will draw a 3D plot of the world on matplotlib / basemap. If you want to configure the region over which it is specified, specify the latitude and longtitudes of your region in the Basemap() method